# Redirect URL with PHP parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, parameters

I have searched and tried various topics regarding redirecting URLs with PHP parameters to URLs without, but can't get it to work.

I have the following URL:

```
http://www.example.nl/?option=com_neorecruit&task=offer_view&id=82&Itemid=9
```

Which needs to be redirected to simply

```
http://www.example.nl/
```

The snippets I found so far lead me to this, which I added in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_neorecruit&task=offer_view&id=82&Itemid=9
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.nl/ [R=301,L]
```

But I can't quite get it to work properly. Can anyone help me out or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_neorecruit&task=offer_view&id=82&Itemid=9$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.nl/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it makes no difference.

Comment: try to use \ before & like `\&` in string.